# how to use '|' in part of the whole raw string in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, string

Required:

Check if the text passed includes a possible U.S. zip code, formatted as follows: exactly 5 digits, and sometimes, but not always, followed by a dash with 4 more digits. The zip code needs to be preceded by at least one space, and cannot be at the start of the text.

My Code:

```
import re
def check_zip_code (text):
  result = re.search(r"^.* +\d{5}", text)
  return result != None
```

For the occasional `r"\-\d{4}"` (a dash with 4 more digits), I tried to include it by changing line 3 to:

`result = re.search(r"^.* +\d{5}|\-\d{4}", text)`

But it does not work.

I have the following questions:

1. How to solve the above zip code problem?
2. How to partially use `|` in the whole raw string?
   (e.g. `"a1|2"` can match either `a1` or `a2`)

Some of the test cases:

```
print(check_zip_code("The zip codes for New York are 10001 thru 11104.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("90210 is a TV show")) # False
print(check_zip_code("Their address is: 123 Main Street, Anytown, AZ 85258-0001.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("The Parliament of Canada is at 111 Wellington St, Ottawa, ON K1A0A9.")) # False
```

Comment: `|` isn't appropriate here; the four extra digits aren't an *alternative* to the 5-digit zip code, they're an optional extension to it.  Add `(-\d{4})?` to express this (or perhaps `(?:-\d{4})`, so you aren't uselessly defining a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an optional group, not an alternation. Additionally, add a negative lookahead at the beginning. That said, you can use:

```
(?!^)\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/SxaYzc/1/).